# Can't delete a PFObject?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

i tried to delete a PFObject but i get a this error :

```
[Error]: object not found for delete (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.0)
```

here my code

```
var newQuery = PFQuery(className: "Transfer")
newQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(object.objectId!, block: { (newObject, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        println("newObjectId : \(newObject!.objectId)")
        newObject!.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock( { (success, err) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                   if success {
                         println("Deleted Successfully")
                   }
                 } else {
                     println("Error : \(err?.localizedDescription) \(err?.userInfo)")
                }
        })

   } else {
       println("Error : \(error?.localizedDescription) \(error?.userInfo)")
   }
})
```

i println() some of the value of that newObject i fetched, and all is right, so i don't understand why it can't found the objet for delete ?

Comment: Why `newObject!.fetchIfNeeded()` ?  The get just fetched it.

Comment: i know , i put it there to see if i can works, that's all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happens because the object has a read only permission. check this [thread](https://parse.com/questions/hi-i-have-tried-to-delete-some-objects-in-a-classbut-it-is-showing-an-error-object-not-found-for-delete-code-101-version-1115what-could-be-the-reasoncan-you-help-me-to-get-a-solution) for details

Good luck